# React.js focus on text input after submit/enter not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component that when the user hits submit (or enter) a new question is presented with a text input, the users enters in an answer and hits submits (this repeats until the final question is answered).

All works except that it's not focusing no matter if I add a ref or autofocus.  I'm unsure what to do at this juncture and can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.

Could I get some assistance on, when the user hits submit, it focuses on the next text input.  I'm using styled components below in my code so the text input would be `inputStyle`

```
 class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      value1: '',
      value2: '',
      value3: '',
      value4: '',
      value5: '',
      value6: '',
      value7: '',
      newValue: '',
      submitted: false,
      input1: 0,
      input2: 0,
      input3: 0,
      input4: 0,
      input5: 0,
      input6: 0,
      input7: 0,
      display: 'block',
      currentStep: 1,
      whitebox: 'block'
    };

    this.handleFirstChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value1');
    this.handleSecondChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value2');
    this.handleThirdChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value3');
    this.handleFourthChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value4');
    this.handleFifthChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value5');
    this.handleSixthChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value6');
    this.handleSeventhChange = event => this.handleChange(event, 'value7');
    this.handleSubmit = event => this._handleSubmit(event);
  }

  handleChange(event, type) {
    let newState = {};
    newState[type] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  _handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.currentStep > 6) {
      this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
      this.setState({ display: 'none' });
      this.setState({ whitebox: 'none' });
    } else {
      this.setState({ currentStep: this.state.currentStep + 1 });
    }
  }

  inputHolderStyle(style, step) {
    const displayProp = step === this.state.currentStep ? 'block' : 'none';

    return {
      // background: `url(${style}) no-repeat center center`,
      // backgroundSize: 'cover',
      // border: 'white 1px solid',
      // background: '#00B5DE',
      display: displayProp
    };
  }

  focus() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      marginTop: '50px',
      color: 'white',
      top: '25px',
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '320px',
      textAlign: 'center',
      border: 'white 1px solid',
      padding: '1em',
      borderRadius: '3px',
      display: this.state.whitebox
    };
    let question = null;
    const show = this.state.visible;
    if (show) {
      question = (
        <div>
          <Crawler
            properName1={this.state.value1}
            noun1={this.state.value2}
            properName2={this.state.value3}
            properName3={this.state.value4}
            noun2={this.state.value5}
            personsName1={this.state.value6}
            noun3={this.state.value7}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <MainContainer>
        <div style={divStyle}>
          <form
            style={{ display: this.state.display }}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          >
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml1, 1)}>
              <InputQuestion>1. Enter A Proper Noun</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input1"
                  type="text"
                  value={this.state.value1}
                  placeholder="Proper Noun"
                  onChange={this.handleFirstChange}
                  ref1={input => {
                    this.textInput = input;
                  }}
                />
                <GrammarNerd>
                  Hint: Use words like Rebel, Hell's Angels, Vegan
                </GrammarNerd>
              </label>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml2, 2)}>
              <InputQuestion>2. Enter A Location</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input2"
                  type="text"
                  ref={input => {
                    this.textInput = input;
                  }}
                  value={this.state.value2}
                  placeholder="Noun"
                  onChange={this.handleSecondChange}
                  ref2={input => {
                    this.textInput = input;
                  }}
                />
                <GrammarNerd>
                  Hint: Use a word such as Base, Bunker, Foxhole, Bedroom
                </GrammarNerd>
              </label>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 3)}>
              <InputQuestion>
                Enter A Proper Noun that Describes Evil
              </InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input3"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter a Proper Noun"
                  value={this.state.value3}
                  onChange={this.handleThirdChange}
                  ref3={input => {
                    this.textInput = input;
                  }}
                />
              </label>
              <GrammarNerd>
                Hint: Use words like Empire, Ottoman, Mongols
              </GrammarNerd>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 4)}>
              <InputQuestion>Describe Something Menacing</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input4"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter a Proper Name"
                  value={this.state.value4}
                  onChange={this.handleFourthChange}
                  ref4="theDiv"
                />
                <GrammarNerd>
                  Hint: Freeze Ray, Mother of All Bombs, Leftover Fruitcake
                </GrammarNerd>
              </label>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 5)}>
              <InputQuestion>Describe a fortified area</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input5"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter a Noun"
                  value={this.state.value5}
                  onChange={this.handleFifthChange}
                  ref5={input => {
                    this.textInput = input;
                  }}
                />
                <GrammarNerd>
                  Hint: Castle, Bunker, Planet, Safe Space
                </GrammarNerd>
              </label>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 6)}>
              <InputQuestion>A Woman's Name</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input6"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="A Woman's Name"
                  value={this.state.value6}
                  onChange={this.handleSixthChange}
                  ref6={input => {
                    this.textInput = input;
                  }}
                />
              </label>
              <GrammarNerd>
                Hint: Astrid, Diana, Mononoke, Peach{' '}
              </GrammarNerd>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolder style={this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 7)}>
              <InputQuestion>Describe a large area of mass</InputQuestion>
              <label>
                <InputStyle
                  name="input7"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter a Noun"
                  value={this.state.value7}
                  onChange={this.handleSeventhChange}
                  ref7={input => {
                    this.textInput = input;
                  }}
                />
              </label>
              <GrammarNerd>
                Galaxy, Planet, Wal Mart
              </GrammarNerd>
            </InputHolder>
            <InputHolderSubmit>
              <SubmitButton onClick={this.focus} type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </InputHolderSubmit>
          </form>
        </div>
        <NextQuestion>
          {question}
        </NextQuestion>
      </MainContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default NameForm;
```

I have left some of my code I've tested (ref and autofocus) as well as some of the functions that don't seem to break the code, but are not working either.

Thank you for your help

Comment: try giving each input a different ref name

Comment: I gave that a shot, did not work, should I modify something in my function?

Comment: I think you want to remove all the autoFocus as well, and when you call submit, focus the appropriate input using the ref `this.yourSpecificInput.focus();`

Comment: so say like from question 4 to question 5 it'd be `this.inputHolderStyle(ml3, 5).focus()`?

Comment: also I'm new at React so apologies for messed up code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WORKING EXAMPLE AUTOFOCUS [DEMO](http://rich-talk.surge.sh/)**

The following code is a simplified sample implementation of what are you looking to do.... check it out and run it and let me know if this helps!!! Happy coding =]!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class AutoFocusText extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            active: 0,
            questions: [
                "how are you?",
                "whats your name?",
                "is reactjs awesome?"
            ],
            value: "",
            answers: []
        };

        this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
        this.renderQuestion = this.renderQuestion.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    renderQuestion() {
        const { questions, active, value } = this.state;

        if (active >= questions.length) return <div>You're Done!</div>;

        return questions
            .filter((quest, index) => index === active) // get next question
            .map(quest =>    // map over selected question, the key prop allows react to
                <FormElement // unmount and mount the components properly, thereby focussing correctly
                    key={active}
                    text={quest}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />
            );
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    }

    submitHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const answers = [...this.state.answers, this.state.value]; //push new value to answsers array without mutation
        const value = ""; // clear input
        const active = this.state.active + 1; // index pointer

        this.setState({ answers, value, active });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* Form Wrapper */}
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    {this.renderQuestion()}
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.answers.map((ans, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                {ans}
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the `FormElement` component that manages focusing the text input...

```
class FormElement extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //focus text input upon mounting component 
        this.textInput.focus();
    }

    render() {
        const { text, value, onChange } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <p>
                    {text}
                </p>
                <input
                    ref={el => {
                        this.textInput = el;
                    }}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    type="text"
                    value={value}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks man.  I'm involved on a project with the house but as soon as I come up for air I will try this

Comment: wow, thank you for this.  It worked well.  I followed you on Twitter/Git and am deeply appreciative.  Thank you for solving this puzzle piece for me, lots of work ahead of me restructuring some stuff but this is great!

Comment: I had one final question, let's say I wanted to take the answers that are generated as an `<li>` and pass them as props. I'm a little lost on doing that at the moment.

Comment: You would pass them from the parent Component to whichever child need access `<Child answers={this.state.answers}`. You would then have access to the anwsers in the `Child` component as `this.props.answers`. You can then continue to pass them down the inheritance chain as follows `<ChildInChild answers={this.props.answers}` and so on and so forth. If children deeper than a few layers need access then it may be getting to a point in which you would consider using Redux.  Let me know if this helped or if I can further clarify =].

Comment: that makes sense and I understand (Redux is next on my list learning, but not there yet) .  So once they are passed and you wanted the values broken down into individual answers in the child component - something you need Redux for or still doable with just React?  (also, I wish there was some super badge or something people could give when folks like you are so giving with info!)

Comment: lol, no worries bro.  Redux just takes the store from the components and keeps it in one global store thereby eliminating the need to to pass state through tons of layers of layers. It is best used on large projects.  This being said, anything can be done with vanilla React but Redux is helpful to manage complex state inheritance chains.  To access the individual anwser in the child you would simply need to use them like any other array, for instance `map` over them `this.props.answers.map(ans => /*Do Some Stuff*/)` or pull a single instance off the array `let ind = this.props.array[0]`

Answer (score 0):

For fixing consider the following

1. Since you are hiding each question using display:none, they are still rendered into the DOM, thus every ref will be executed regardless of which question you are on. You are assigning to this.textInput so this.textInput will only ever have input7's element.
2. For the same reason, autofocus probably won't work very well as I believe this fires when a react component is **added** to the DOM, not made visible with css.

If I were you I would have a renderQuestion(*step*) method with a switch statement in, which returns the JSX for each case of *step*. Call this after the form element in your main render method with {this.renderQuestion(step)}, do the switch and this way only the active question will be rendered into the DOM. This may help making autoFocus work, I'm not sure. But to be more explicit, ref will now work properly and you can simply do

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.textInput && this.textInput.focus();
}
```

Comment: hey thanks I can try that, that's originally what I want to do and I'm fine for trying that because I want to learn React.  What you advise is a bit over my head and don't exactly know where to start.  I'm not asking you to write out everything for me of course, however do you have a resource (or if there is an easy code) that could help with the renderQuestion(step) ?